# CSS relative and absolute children

Tags: css

I have problem with a background image for an absolute div:

```
.div1 { 
  height:100%;
  positon:relative; 
  top:0; 
}
.div2 {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0; 
}
.image_in_div2 { 
  background: url('img/img1.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover; 
}
```

HTML

```
<div class='div1'>
    <div class='div2'>
         <div class='image_in_div2'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem I have: When I reload the page when the browser is on top of scroll everything is ok. But when I scroll down page and reload, the positioning of `image_in_div2` doesn't start from top of the page, but from top of the visible view.

What I do wrong?

Comment: Sorry, it's unclear to me.

Comment: how do you want? and what is happening?

Comment: What I want - I want image start from beginning of it's parent and not from beginning of current window position

Comment: can you show the image of what is happening currently and how you want ?

Comment: I don't know how to show it. I put background for div as a cover. 2. scroll down for about 200px 3. reload page. 4. scroll to top of page RESULT - 200px from top of page doesn't have image, because image was loaded relative to window, not it's parent div.

Comment: a jsfiddle will overcome this.

Comment: I try many times do something in jsfiddle and I just can't make it work , I do not understand jsfiddle.

Comment: copy the code html code in html section and css code in css section and save it and share it....

Comment: [here's a tutorial](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/tutorial.html) on using jsfiddle

Comment: it's impossible to make it in jsfiddle because in jsfiddle after reload, re-run script, scrolls always go to top of page

Answer (score -1):

First of all you have couple of type errors. `.div1 > positon:relative;` should be `position` and you can remove `-moz-background-size: cover` from `.image_in_div2`.

And, if I got it right, adding `background-attachment:fixed` might solve your problem.

Comment: I do not understand why but I change position absolute to fixed for another container for that divs and it work. But now I have problem with other fixed backgrounds in other divs ...strange